# Show alert on screen when app is in background

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I want to show multiple alerts after some time interval when the app is in background.

Currently I am using local notification to show the alert but I cannot detect action when user presses the cancel button of local notification.

```
 UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

            if (localNotif == nil)
                return;
            localNotif.fireDate = [NSDate date];
            localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

                    // Notification details
                    localNotif.alertBody = @"This is local notification message.";
                    // Set the action button
                    localNotif.alertAction = @"View";
                    localNotif.alertAction = @"Yes";

            localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
            [localNotif release];
```

Is there any other way I can show alert on screen when app is in background ?

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to detect if you user decided to ignore your [`UILocalNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html).
Since you can not show a [`UIAlertView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html) in the background your only option is to use [`UILocalNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

But as you state you can not detect if the user clicked the cancel button, also with iOS6 and the notification center there no longer is a cancel button. Only if user selected to show you notifications as alerts will there be a close button. Still you can not detect that you notification is closed or not views at all.

Your only option is to keep spamming the use with notification until the app is opened. But it is considered bad user experience and could make you app hated by users.

Comment: Even with iOS6 there is a **Close** button if i select notification style as **Alert** from settings for that app.

Comment: @ManthanPatel Correct but default it is the notification center and you will only be informed about the user action of an `UILocalNotification` if the user choice to open your thru the notification.

Answer (score 0):

this not posible in ios.only using push notification you can display it.

Comment: Can we detect the cancel button action on push notification?

Comment: while recieve push notification then following method call and do some proccess on it.- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    
    for (id key in userInfo)
    {
        NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [userInfo objectForKey:key]);
    }
    
}

Comment: @nitinkachhadiya that method is only called if you app is running in the foreground when the notification is received. When your app is in the background no method is called.

Comment: @rckoenes yes you are right, the method can only be detected if you press to see the notification and not if you close the push notification